# Why does function return false after checking only one value in loop

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, for-loop

Trying to check if a value exists within an array, but my nested if statement is returning 
false even if the value exists in the array. This worked until I added an else to my loop, now it only works if the value to check for is the first index.

```js
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var inp = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number to see if it is in the array:"));

function checkIfInArray(n, anArray) {

  for (var i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] == n) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(checkIfInArray(inp, num));
```

Comment: Did you expect the function to `return false;` *multiple times*? How would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you have the check inside the `for`-loop, the code inside the `for`-loop runs only once because now that you've added an `else`, it will ALWAYS return something.

The correct way to return false if nothing was found, would be to add the `return false` after the for-loop finishes.

```
for(var i = 0;i < anArray.length;i++)
{
     if(num[i] == n)
     {
          return true;
     }
} 

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will stop & exit at the first "return". If you add a return false after the loop, it will ensure that if the function haven't been exited after the loop (= not in array), it will return false :

```js
var num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var inp = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number to see if it is in the array:"));

function checkIfInArray(n,anArray)
{
    for(var i = 0;i < anArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(num[i] == n)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

var result = checkIfInArray(inp,num);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
    function checkIfInArray(n,anArray)
    {
        for(var i = 0;i < anArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(num[i] == n)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }  
        return false; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement to return at first check, whether true or false

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem while doing my react app.
We can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), this will return `true` if **atleast one** condition is true.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const twoExists = array.some(value => value === 2)
console.log(twoExists)
// expected output: true
```